# Abstracting out Autofac's factory method support

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, autofac

What is the right way to abstract out Autofac's factory method support?

I keep getting this exception:

> This resolve operation has already ended. When registering components using lambdas, 
>   the IComponentContext 'c' parameter to the lambda cannot be stored. Instead, either
>   resolve IComponentContext again from 'c', or resolve a Func<> based factory to create 
>   subsequent components from.

Here is my attempt to wrap it up.

```
public void Register<T>(Func<IFactoryContext, T> factoryMethod)
{
   _containerBuilder.Register<Func<Type, T>>(c => {
      var ctx = c.Resolve<IComponentContext>();
      return request => factoryMethod(new AutofacFactoryContext(ctx));
   });
}
```

I've even tried

```
public void Register<T>(Func<IFactoryContext, T> factoryMethod)
{
   _containerBuilder.Register<Func<Type, T>>(c => {
      var ctx = c.Resolve<IComponentContext>();
      return request => factoryMethod(new AutofacFactoryContext((IComponentContext)ctx.Resolve(request)));
   });
}
```

I want to have a method that returns `T`.

`AutofacFactoryContext` is an implementation of `IFactoryContext`, which is just a wrapping of Autofac's `IComponentContext`.

In the end this is the result I'm expecting:

```
 bootstrapper.Register<IFoo>(c => new Foobar());
```

In using the container:

```
 var foobar = container.Resolve<IFoo>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the following would work:

```
public void Register<T>(Func<IFactoryContext, T> factoryMethod)
{
   _containerBuilder.Register<Func<Type, T>>(c =>
      request => {
          var ctx = c.Resolve<IComponentContext>();
          factoryMethod(new AutofacFactoryContext(ctx));
   });
}
```

However, please note that this would make no use of the `request`, just like your first example. As I am not really sure what you are trying to achieve here, I can't propose a better alternative.

Comment: I'm just learning how to abstract out autofac so that my project doesn't have to have direct dependencies on it - its in another assembly.

Comment: @DanielA.White: Normally, you should use the DI container only in your composition root. This is a very constraint area of your project. Switching the DI container would require you to only change this constraint area. I am not sure that warrants the effort.